# Remove Unit Tests in XCode 8

Tags: xcode8

XCode auto-generates unit tests for projects, and these OFTEN fail due to bugs in XCode/OSX etc (plus, we have external unit testing an all of our "important" source code)

I want to completely remove these auto-generated unit tests from the project, but it seems that the strategies used for each previous version of xcode no longer exist with XCode8.

Does anyone know how to disable/remove the auto-generated "Tests" folder created by XCode in XCode 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, I found the answer immediately after posting the question.

What I was missing is I hadn't clicked here:

[image: The little "targets" button]

Which opened up the targets menu, where I could delete targets.

Before clicking it looked like this:

[image: Before click]

And afterwards, I could see the targets view.

[image]